# Why -1 * 0 = -0 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

As reported in the title:
Why in Javascript `-1 * 0 = -0` ?

[image]

How I can prevent it?
I would have expected to have `0` as result.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it? Is it causing any problems in your program's logic?

Comment: If you don't want negative values use `Math.abs`.

Comment: "*I would have expected to have `0` as result.*" OK but I don't get where the problem with a negative zero is. What specific issue is it causing?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a specific reason for wanting to prevent that?

If your concern is related to the fact that you want to get `0` instead of `-0` you don't need to worry about that since  `-0 === 0` return true

```js
console.log(-1 * 0)
console.log(-1 * 0 === 0)

const turnItToNegative = n => -1 * n 

const myNumber = turnItToNegative(0)

if (myNumber === 0) {
  console.log('This is still zero, don\'t worry')
}
```

Comment: @gixlg That isn't a problem: `\`${-0}\`==="0"`

Comment: @gixlg Are you actually getting an unexpected result (outside of the console)? If so, show the code that's producing the unexpected result. If not, then you're worrying about nothing.

Comment: Ya, the only time you'd have an issue is if you need to differentiate between -0 and 0.  But you'd know it if you needed it.